# MATLAB how to query a name in google

Tags: matlab, search

In MATLAB, we have table of movie information as follows:

```
 movieId          title                     genres           
 _______    __________________    ___________________________

 10         'GoldenEye (1995)'    'Action|Adventure|Thriller'
```

The table contains many rows with many movie informarion.

**Questions :**

- I would like to obtain some statistics about year distribution of movies. How can I do this with/without using loops. That is suggest a code please that extracts the years for all movies in the table (e.g. using regexp() etc.). All the years are with the partheneses.
- Another interesting question is for a given title (in this case 'GoldenEye') would it be possible to query that title in Google and obtain the resulting wikipedia page if it there exists. Once sucessful, I would like to import all the text in the wikipage.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask]. Ask only 1 question per question (i.e. this should be two separate questions). Also, you need to first demonstrate that you have tried to solve this problem yourself by posting the code of your attempt and explaining what went wrong (i.e. what errors you got or how the output differs from what you were trying to accomplish). As it stands, this is a very poor question.

Comment: This is the currently still working toolbox? (not 100% checked, but I think it was still working in 2015.)http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35693-urlread2

Comment: Thanks for the information and reminding me of the rules. I will have them in mind.

@GameOfThrows: useful source thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A robust solution without unnecessary type conversions, array expansions, loops, and deprecated functions:

```
% Generate sample data
T = table([10; 11; 12], {'GoldenEye (1995)'; '12 Monkeys (1995)'; 'Aladdin (1992)'}, ...
    {'Action|Adventure|Thriller'; 'Action|Adventure|Thriller'; 'Cartoon'}, ...
    'VariableNames', {'ID', 'Name', 'Genre'} ...
    );

% Parse years and convert to a numeric array
ReleaseYear = regexp(T.Name, '(?<=\()(\d*)(?=\))', 'Match');
ReleaseYear = [ReleaseYear{:}]'; % Need to denest the regex return cells
ReleaseYear = str2double(ReleaseYear);

% Obtain distribution of Release Years
UniqueYears = unique(ReleaseYear);
N = histcounts(ReleaseYear, length(UniqueYears));
```

To exclude false matches if the movie title contains numbers, I have used lookbehind (`(?<=\()`) and lookahead (`(?=\))`) assertions to the [`regex`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) calls to only retrieve numbers (`(\d*)`) if they are enclosed with parentheses. You could also just search for `\(\d*\)` patterns and remove the parentheses later.

Regular Expressions are really fun but can be tricky, I suggest checking out [MATLAB's documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html). I've found [Regex101's Python Flavor](https://regex101.com/#python) helps when formulating your regular expressions and the syntax is similar to MATLAB.

Comment: wow, first time I've seen a community wiki, cool!